# How can I change 'References' in capital letters

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a paper with 'article' style.

I just put a reference list by:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{5}
.....
\end{thebibliography}
```

It creates 'References' section.
I, however, want to have section 'REFERENCE'.

P.S.
I want to submit the paper to Seismological research letter electronic seismologist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following definition before `\begin{document}`:

```
\def\refname{REFERENCE}
```